# Databinding can't call static function with String.function()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a function which formats some text

```
fun String.formatTo(): String {
    if (this.isNotEmpty()) {
        val value = this.toDouble()
        return "%.02f".format(value)
    }
    return ""
}
```

And I want to apply this fun to my textView, using databinding, so I called in textView `android:text="@{viewModel.text.formatTo()}"`, importing class in `data` of my layout

```
<data>
    <import type="com.project.utils.extensions.ExtKt"/>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.project.ViewModel" />
</data>
```

But I've got an error throw building:

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find method formatTo() in class java.lang.String
```

What is a problem?

Answer (score 5):

Create an `object` named `ExtKt` (or anything you want) and define your extension function in it and annotate it with `@JvmStatic` like below

```
@JvmStatic
fun String.formatTo(): String {
    if (this.isNotEmpty()) {
        val value = this.toDouble()
        return "%.02f".format(value)
    }
    return ""
}
```

**Update**

```
android:text="@{ExtKt.formatTo()}"
```

Comment: This function located in file (.kt), not a class, so I cant add this annotation, because only members in named objects and companion objects can be annotated with '@JvmStatic

Comment: @Strangelove consider using an object to solve that issue

Answer (score 2):

Databinding is still Java modules, so some features of kotlin like extension functions can't be used there. The only thing you can do here - create specific function in your `ViewModel` class.

```
class ViewModel {
    val text: String
    ...
    fun getDisplayText(): String = text.formatTo()
}
```

May be you want to use calculated properties.

```
val displayText: String get() = text.formatTo()
```

Anyway, your xml call will look like following:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.displayText}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider use MediatorLiveData:

```
class ViewModel(
    val list: MutableLiveData<List<String>> = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
) {

    val listStr = MediatorLiveData<String>()

    init {
        listStr .addSource(list, Observer {
            listStr .postValue(ViewModel.joinList(it))
        })
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun joinList(list: List<String>): String {
            return list.joinToString(separator = ", ")
        }
    }
}
```

And than in the xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/items"
    android:text="@{viewModel.listStr}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```